# SceneKit: how to pass custom vertex attributes to shaders?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, scenekit, metal

This is per-vertex data which cannot fit into any of the existing semantics (vertex, normal, color, etc.). I need to send the data to gpu for per-vertex manipulation.